# Does test-driven development consider a part of behavior-driven development?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, bdd

More precisely does writing unit tests consider as BDD practice?

Does unite testing consider as a part of BDD/TDD or both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several types of tests: unit tests, acceptance tests, integration tests. And there are several development practices, like TDD or BDD. So, BDD is not only about acceptance testing. BDD can be done unit tests level. Here is some of [Dan North thoughts](http://dannorth.net/introducing-bdd/) about difference between BDD and TDD when we speak about unit-testing:

- Test method names should be sentences (throw the 'Test' word away)
- Focused on behavior sentence template (start test name with 'Should' or 'ShouldNot')
- etc

There are different BDD frameworks for different types of tests. E.g. [SpecFlow](http://www.specflow.org/) for acceptance BDD, or [NSpec](http://nspec.org/) for unit level BDD.

So, answering your questions:

- If unit tests done in BDD style, then writing those tests is BDD practice
- Again, unit-testing could be part of BDD, if we are not talking about acceptance tests. Keep in mind, that unit-testing could be done separately from TDD/BDD, e.g. when you writing tests for existing code.

Comment: I think that the majority of unit tests that I've seen are focused more on the implementation details than on their functional behavior. These types of tests tend to be brittle and needlessly specific. When tests focus more on what needs to happen instead of how things are accomplished, your unit tests find a common ground that resembles BDD.

Comment: Agree. Last few years I tend to write tests in style of human-readable live documentation, which does not depend on implementation. But at the beginning I also used names like `TestMethodFoo` which become mess after simple renaming of MethodFoo :)